# Page style not applied till page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code below

```
  var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var link  = document.createElement('link');
  link.href = 'https://d13pxqgp3ixdbh.cloudfront.net/uploads/assets/16642844559b6e4cea4ae2fe0a54b4596fe23cb906.css';
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  var link_2 = document.createElement("link");
  link_2.href = "https://d13pxqgp3ixdbh.cloudfront.net/uploads/assets/166489336485398db24429f7e1e1a9bc5de498582e.css";
  link_2.rel = "stylesheet";
  head.appendChild(link);
  head.appendChild(link_2);
```

When I enter the page the styling is not applied but after like 0.5seconds it applies. But i'd like it to apply instantly.

Comment: Don't wait for DOMContentLoaded, then... why do you even load this via JS to begin with? Why not just put the links directly into the HTML?

Comment: Oh I removed that DOMContentLoaded, but it's still the same

Comment: Well if you have a big CSS file it can take a moment to download it and parse it (if the browser didn't cache it already), and also if this JS code is not until later in your HTML file, then other content will be added first. But again...why not just put `<link` tags in the HTML in the first place? It's not clear why you'd do this via JS.

Comment: I cannot add directly via HTML as I'm using dev platform and it needs to be done via js

Comment: Which dev platform, exactly?

Comment: I cannot tell here publicly, why exactly does it matter, I just need my problem solved.

Comment: Why not? I doubt it's a state secret, and also we don't know who you are or who you work for. Realistically it might be useful info. Anyway, have you done anything like looked at the browser's network tool to see if there's a download speed delay, or if the bottleneck is after that point?

Comment: You can prioritise your styles to download first, what you have to do is set you rel to preload and as to style, Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload